# Movieplayercontroller using a m4v with two audio tracks

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, m4v

I need use in my App a m4v video with two audio tacks. But when I play the video, it starts with the two audio tracks at the same time. I need to load the audio track with the device's default language (English by default).

Here is my code:

> ```
> _moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
> [_moviePlayer shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
> _moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
> [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:_moviePlayer];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerController` just as well as the wrapping `MPMoviePlayerViewController` do not support the selection of audio tracks.

Comment: I can select the tracks, "English" or "Spanish". But when you start sounding both at once.